# jQuery datepicker revert to allow all dates

Tags: jquery

I have this snippet of code that limits date to select to only saturday.

```
$( ".arrival-date" ).datepicker('option','beforeShowDay',function(date){
    var today = date.getDay();
    var result = [(date.getDay() == 6),'',(today == 'Sat' ) ? '': 'Not saturday'];
    return result;
});
```

I however want to reenable all days other times depending on the the selected location and this doesn't work.

```
$(".arrival-date").datepicker();
```

Comment: In that case you need to change the logic to return `result` dependant on the selection of those other fields. However, you've not given us enough information about them or the state they should be in, so we can't really help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to re-enable all days other times depending on the the selected location

Given this requirement you can simply amend the logic to first check what location was selected. If that location allows all days return an empty string, otherwise let execution flow through to your current logic. Try this:

```js
$(".arrival-date").datepicker('option', 'beforeShowDay', function(date) {
  if ($('#yourLocationField').val() === 'Someplace')
    return [true, ''];

  var today = date.getDay();
  var result = [(date.getDay() == 6), '', (today == 'Sat') ? '' : 'Not saturday'];
  return result;
});
```

Comment: Can you include the HTML for `#yourLocationField`? Just interested to see how you interpreted this answer, which is brilliant.

Comment: It could be any form control. Given it's nature I'd guess it would be a `<select />` element, otherwise you'd be relying on user's to type a location name in consistently,.